# Python script sys.argv error

Tags: python, list

This is my first python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Years till 100
import sys

name = sys.argv[1]
age = int(sys.argv[2])
diff = 100 - age

print 'Hello', name + ', you will be 100 in', diff, 'years!'
```

When I run it, it gives the following error:

```
name = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me spot the problem please?

Comment: You should pass parameters to the script. You remember that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the script with any parameters?

```
myscript.py myname 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was not executing the program properly.

I was doing the following:

```
$ chmod u+x pytest3_variable1.py
$ ./pytest3_variable1.py
```

I should have done:

```
$ chmod u+x pytest3_variable1.py
$ ./pytest3_variable1.py Abhinav 22
```

Comment: Yes. But you only need to `chmod` once to make the script executable. After that you can just run the second line. (That is weird that we both put 22 as the age!)

Comment: @beroe Perhaps both of you are 22?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$ python pytest3_variable1.py Abhinav 22
```